# How to run pencilblue on aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pencilblue

I have installed PencilBlue on AWS EC2 instance. i have started PB by using the command `pbctrl start`
Now, how can I access the PencilBlue login page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you run any other web server on EC2, you start the service, open the port in the Security Group, and then open the website in your browser.